# Как мониторить IOPS по процессам в системе?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В статистике Amplify вижу, что периодически какой-то процесс долбит диск. Да нагружает он диск так, что повисает вообще вся система - нет доступа к SSH и веб-серверу. Есть ли какой-то инструмент, позволяющий увидеть историю обращений к диску? И как вообще можно определить, какой процесс нагружает диск?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первая же выдача на запрос: `linux process io usage` ведет [сюда](https://serverfault.com/questions/169676/howto-check-disk-i-o-utilisation-per-process) (остальные на странице тоже выглядят многообещающе)

Comment: @avp ставил эту штуку через apt-get и пытался запустить - приложение вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: Какая из них? (неужели `/proc/diskstats`? :)). Да и в остальных выдачах по запросу ссылки на разные утилиты

Comment: @avp поставил iotop командой `apt-get install iotop`, запускаю через команду `iotop` в консоли и получаю `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: ктото баловался с системным питоном)

Comment: @eri, нет. Выяснилось, что это баг самого iotop. Вместо установки через `apt-get` я клонировал репозиторий с Гитхаба и всё заработало :)